# How to Download file in internal Storage using Volley in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

In my android app I want to download a file from web server to Mobile's Internal Storage using Download Manager in android studio. And also i need to use it inside the Volley function.

**My Code**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
  DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png");
  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
 request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);                
  request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadsActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "banu.jpg");
}
```

In above code I had tried it in button click.

Comment: `I had tried it in button click` and what is the problem with it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I got the file in internal storage of Mobile but the file is in android folder (i.e) path: ``Internal Storage/Android/data/packagename/files/Download``    but i want to make my file download in seperate folder

Answer (score 0):

To download from an URL you need to use the `AsyncTask` process then save image using Bitmap.

```
your class...ACTIVITY...{
 oncreateFunction(){
  // your codes...
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

     Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png");
     mTask = new DownloadTask()
                    .execute(new URL(uri));
     }
    });
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,Bitmap>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){

        // if need to show progress
    }

    // Background Task/non-UI thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL...urls){
        URL url = urls[0];
        HttpURLConnection conn= null;

        try{

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

            return bmp;

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){

        if(result!=null){

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            Uri imageInternalUri = saveImageToInternalStorage(result);              
            mImageViewInternal.setImageURI(imageInternalUri);
        }else {

            // show error if any
        }
    }
 }

 protected Uri saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap){

    ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

    File file = wrapper.getDir("Images",MODE_PRIVATE);

    file = new File(file, "yourFileUnique"+".jpg");

    try{
        OutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

     }catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
     return savedImageURI;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Riad .... In your code it shows ``Cannot resolve method 'execute(Url)'`` error

Comment: did you `import android.os.AsyncTask;`?

Comment: Thanks @Riad... ``Cannot resolve symbol 'Url'`` error also i am getting

Comment: yeah it working... need to add `onPostExecute` to show the image

Comment: here we don't need the sdcard right? our file will get saved only in internal storage right?

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkImageView` automatically loads image from background queue and cancel request.

`ImageLoader` use  for detached view and automatically uses memory from disk cache.

we can use `NetworkImageView` for volley downloading image. Belows are example.

**layout_example.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your **MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_example);
    NetworkImageView nv = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    // image for loading...
    nv.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.default_image); 
    //ImgController from your code.
    nv.setImageUrl(imageUrl, ImgController.getInstance().getImageLoader()); 
}
```

**Edit**

- with Volley supports the download of strings, images and JSON.

Volley is not suitable for large downloads or streaming (Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing,So large downloads will use a lot of memory).

You should use the `DownloadManager` for large downloads.

**Downloading images**

There are two ways of doing this with Volley:

- `ImageRequest` – this gets an image at a URL, returning a Bitmap. You can set the required size. Volley does the processing off the main thread
- `ImageLoader` – this loads and caches images from remote Url’s. It’s like a manager of multiple ImageRequest’s. It’s ideal for loading images into lists and grids. You can include a memory cache

and Our special image view through `NetworkImageView`.

For more information it'll help you :https://mobikul.com/downloading-files-using-volley/

I hope it'll help you...!

Comment: in your code did you write code for downloading function anywhere?

Comment: In my question I didn't mention it as a image. I need to download file only whether it may be a pdf file or image or doc file

Comment: please check the link end of  the answer

Comment: I have already tried that link.. but my app gets crashed when I used it

Comment: I think it'll help you : https://androidknowledgeblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/download-pdf-from-server-android/